# iis return only first object from entity framework response

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, iis, asp.net-web-api

i call $http.get from my angular controller

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/users/')
              .success(function (response) {
                  console.log(response);
              });
```

and get the response as a Json array
the first object is OK but the others is empty
this is the response:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
 0:Object
 1:Object
 2:Object
 length:3
```

the first object:

```
$id:"1"
ApplicationRole1:Object
ApplicationRoleId:1
ApplyDocuments: Array(0)
CellNum:"000000000"
Department1:Object
DepartmentId:1
```

the other objects is empty like this:

```
Object
$ref: "3"
__proto__:Object
```

i'm using in webApi and entity framework 6 in the server side.
the server returns the Json array with all the object inside.
but when I call it from the client using the IIS server the result return like i explained.

any suggests?
thank you

Comment: debug your code before published ..

Comment: this is after i debug the code and like i said in the server side the Json array object is returned with all the data

Comment: add your controller code

Comment: the angular controller or the webApi controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the same issue, 
in your GET function add this line,

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

this will not return the relation of the object.